# Получить список ломбардов

Tags: яндекс-карта-api, yandex-places-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощь Яндекс API Поиска по организациям, можно получить список всех ломбардов Москвы и Московской области.

Я указываю:

```
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Москва Ломбарды&results=500&lang=ru_RU&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Я получаю список из 500 ломбардов, но мне надо получить список всех ломбардом, их более 1500.

Мне надо разбить запрос через параметр bbox, но я не понимаю, как выставлять координаты. Просьба помочь разобраться.

Comment: Похоже, вы пытаетесь вместо поиска конкретной организации около точки (для чего был создан сервис) выгружать в свою базу списки объектов из ППО Яндекса, что является нарушением ПС. Не надо так делать. Тем более, что релевантность ответа после первых нескольких строчек достаточно невысока, чтобы использовать это как полноценный список организаций.

Comment: Понял вас. Скажите, как можно получить список всех ломбардов Москвы и области?

Comment: Если вас интересует информация с Яндекса — никак. Они ясно дают понять, что сервис развивается для прямого онлайн доступа к свежей информации (не важно, напрямую или через API), а не для выгрузки данных. Что в принципе логично — зачем им помогать создателям конкурирующих решений на основе их же данных? Быть может есть сторонние сервисы, такую инфу распространяющие, но я за этим уже не слежу, может кто другой подскажет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!